# Get percentage in datatables

Tags: php, sql, oracle, datatable

I am using datatable plugin to display a SQL query results. I am calculating the percentage from my query but it gives me a wrong value. Is there any way to get the results from datatable?

[image]

In image, i `33` is the total `(23+4+2+4)`. I need to get percentage `(23/33)*100` next to the value `23`. is this possible?

```
SELECT AIP.TERMID,
       (select count(RAU.TERMNAME)
          FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU
          WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND
                RAU.VOCID = 4) as page_views,
       (select sum(count(RAU.TERMNAME))
          FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU
          WHERE RAU.VOCID = 4 and
                RAU.TERMID in (select AIP.TERMID
                                 from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
                                 GROUP BY AIP.TERMID)
          group by RAU.VOCID) as page_views_sum,
       (select sum(count(AIP2.TERMID))
          from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP2
          join REPORT_API_USAGE RAU
            ON (RAU.TERMID = AIP2.TERMID AND
                RAU.VOCID = 4)
          where aip2.ctype = 'download'
          GROUP by AIP2.termid) as download_sum,
       (select sum(count(AIP2.TERMID))
          from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP2
          join REPORT_API_USAGE RAU
            ON (RAU.TERMID = AIP2.TERMID AND
                RAU.VOCID = 4)
          where aip2.ctype = 'event'
          GROUP by AIP2.termid) as event_sum,
       COUNT(case
               when aip.ctype = 'download' then 1
               else null
             end) as page_download,
       COUNT(case
               when aip.ctype = 'event' then 1
               else null
             end) as page_event
  from REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
  GROUP BY AIP.TERMID
```

`download_sum` & `event_sum` are wrong.

This how i am displaying the result

`<div class="percent-container"> 
          <div class="percent-count"> <div class="percent-count-value"> <?php print $RowT->page_event; ?> </div>  <div class="percent-value"><?php print round(($RowT->page_event / $RowT->event_sum) * 100); ?>% </div> </div>

          <div class="percent-item"> <div class="percent" style="width: <?php print round(($RowT->page_event / $RowT->event_sum) * 100); ?>%"> </div> </div> 
         </div>`

Comment: Please share your SQL query, it's hard to help without seeing your SQL

Comment: SELECT (a)/(SUM(*)*100) WHERE a is 23, sum(*) is the sum of all items

Comment: Is there any way 2 get the total sum of `COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'download' then 1 else null end) as page_download,` &
 `COUNT(case when aip.ctype = 'event' then 1 else null end) as page_event` from query

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH data (value) AS (
    SELECT 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    VALUE, ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(VALUE) OVER () * 100) PERCENTAGE
FROM
    data
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".